# How to join values from multiple rows in a single column?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project to find the association rule of items for Market dataset. I have a huge database that contains multi-tables. The output I got from this query

```
select sales_fact_1997.customer_id, sales_fact_1997.product_id,     
product.product_name
from sales_fact_1997 , product
where sales_fact_1997.product_id = product.product_id
group by sales_fact_1997.customer_id , sales_fact_1997.product_id
order by sales_fact_1997.customer_id, product.product_name;
```

is like that:

```
customer_id     product_id      product_name
13               1466           Hot Dogs
13               937            American Cole Slaw 
13               10             Akron City Map
...
```

Is there a way to get the output in this format:

```
customer_id     product_id      product_name
13              1466,937,10     Hot Dogs, American Cole Slaw, Akron City Map
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(product_id) AS product_ids,
       ...
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY customer_id;
```